# How to make countdown timer using database in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, timer, countdown

I'm new in JavaScript. I'm currently making an exam application with countdown timer. I've used JavaScript timer with cookie but the problem is when the computer is shutting down the cookie is lost because the computer is frozen by deepfreeze.

My question is how to make countdown timer using database? And how to make it pause the timer when browser is closed and then resume the timer when the browser is re-opened?

Comment: Post your code, we are here to help, not do it for you

Comment: lan: I think he didn't post his code for that exact reason, to not come across as asking people to code it for him. I used to have the same misconception back when I started out on here.

Comment: The OP may just be asking for some advice on if such a system is possible, and what would be a good direction to go with its implementation.

Comment: @Wingblade: generally there is an expectation of prior (code) effort here. Brief questions that ask for rough guidance _may_ have had plenty of effort spent on them, but experienced helpers tend to find this is not true in the majority of cases. Also, how-would-I-do-this questions are sometimes not a good fit, since questions are meant to be useful for future readers, but these tend to be localised to OP requirements.

Comment: OP, if you have a logged in user, you should ensure the user cannot answer after their time limit expires on the server. You can also render a JS timer, but if the user is able to disable this by hibernating the machine or turning it off, they still won't be able to get around the server limit.

Comment: (I'm assuming 'deepfreeze' is power-off hibernation).

Comment: @halfer: I am 100% aware of that, that's why I referred to what OP did as a "misconception". At first sight posting code may feel like going up to your teacher with your unfinished homework like "finish it", but going up to them and asking them a question so you can use the answer in your solution of the problem may seem more logical. But eventually new users get used to providing their own code if possible.

Comment: Yes, I've add some function in PHP to update expired time when users answer (in my case use with radio button) so if the radio button onclick the time will be updated, but it count by the range between the time in each computer and the time test started. and I've found problem if the computer is shutdown or when user leave the test for a while, the timer is still running because it's based on server time. I use PHP for updating time and javascript for displaying current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is use ajax within a setInterval, say every 10 seconds, then you store a value as the max time in the database ( in seconds ).

Every time the ajax call ( jQuery.post() ) you have a server side script that would decrease the time you have in the database by the timeout set in the interval, so for a quick example.

You start with 360 seconds ( 10 min ) then as your javascript interval calls ajax every 10 seconds you decrease that value in the database by 10 second, whenever the server side code is ran.

I do something vary similar to track hours spent entering data.

This way as long as the page is open, and that javascript code runs it will continue to count down, you could return the time remaining and when its less then 0 prompt some kind of message.  If they left for a while or the computer "Froze" it would start right back where it left off once the page was loaded again.

The only real issue I see is you would get what is called race conditions unless you had a way to identify each user and give them each their own timers.  To expand on that imagine I have 2 users User A and User B, if just user A visits the page everything is fine.  But if both A and B use the page at the same time they will both be reducing the time by 10 seconds each for a total of 20 seconds, for each call of their respective ajax requests.

For that you could use some sort of really basic user login setup.  So when they return they would put in their username, and that would let you assign the right timer to them.

Comment: is it possible that ajax can update database? sorry, I'm not well in ajax...

Comment: Ajax is used to call a server side script, think of it like submitting a form, but without the form.  Then the server side script would access the database etc. Id suggest reading the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any of your specifics (database type, interface, etc), all I can suggest are some generalities:

1. save the cookie as a file instead (using PHP's [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), etc)
2. save the value of the cookie as a database value (could be any table, any column, most likely of the date/time type)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about making such a timer in general is by not storing how many seconds are left, but simply when the timer started. You can then use straightforward maths to determine the time left.

On the PHP page your javascript is on you should have some PHP code that creates a some form of entry for the user when the page is loaded. This can be a text file, a MySQL entry, or maybe something in a PHP session if PHP session lifetimes are good enough for your use case. In that entry you store the system time of your server from when the timer was first started, using PHP's `time()` for example. If an entry already exists that one should be kept of course, so users can refresh the page without resetting your timer by accident. This page should also give your javascript a variable containing the time left.

Then you have a second PHP script that you can call with your javascript (using HTTP requests) that returns the time left on the timer `$timer_max - (time() - $stored_time)` You can then have your javascript check the timer every so and so many seconds, and simply interpolate the time in between on your client so it looks like the timer is actively counting down to your user.

The advantage of the start-time based approach is that it is more accurate, whereas an approach that counts down every 10 seconds or so can get inaccurate over time since javascript's timeout function isn't that strict about its timing. It's also very useful with something like PHP that doesn't run constant update loops, but rather just runs a script whenever it gets requested from the webserver.

EDIT (I missed the part about pausing the timer, my bad.):
For a pausing timer this kind of approach may be not so perfect however one could simply introduce another PHP script to pause the timer, storing the server time of when the timer was paused in the entry along with when it was started, then when the user returns the `$stored_time` could be set to `time() - ($pause_time - $stored_time)`, where `$paused_time` is when the timer was paused.

Having the server detect when the browser is closed could either be done by having the user pause the timer before closing the page, having it auto-send a HTTP request (though that wouldn't work if the browser gets killed by taskmanager for example), or by simply having the server remember the last time when the timer was checked with our second script, and when the user comes back it should check how long the last timer HTTP request was ago, and if it was more than say twice your HTTP request interval ago then that "last timer access" time could be considered the pause time.

Comment: Not so, it really depends on what the details of the implementation are.  Perhaps they only want to track the time that a user is actually visiting the page? Using a set start time would not be the way to go in that situation.  Also if you read the details of the request ... "and how to make it pause the timer when browser is closed and then resume the timer when the browser is re-opened"

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix: I completely missed that part about pausing it. I thought said how to PREVENT it from pausing when the browser closes, so it would keep counting, which is why I suggested the start-time approach. It's like 6am in the morning here, I shouldn't post so late. I shall update my answer a little.

Comment: That's alright, I didn't see it at first either, just my suggestion was fresh in my mind because I just setup something similar.  To be honest there is no 100% accurate way to time this as there is no way to know when a user leaves the page, or when a browser is closed.

Comment: The option I explained in my edit seems like a pretty good way to go, it's essentially a timeout on the serverside which should be able to detect the time the browser is closed pretty accurately, given the HTTP request interval is small enough.